# Как в цикле получить список всех датасетов (Delphi)

Tags: delphi

При создании формы всем датасетам делаю присваивание типа:

```
qNotfixrecg.Connection:=Fmain.FDConnection1;
qfirmname.Connection:=Fmain.FDConnection1;
qrecs.Connection:=Fmain.FDConnection1;
qSett.Connection:=Fmain.FDConnection1;
qpassw.Connection:=Fmain.FDConnection1;
qnashti.Connection:=Fmain.FDConnection1;
qprgExcel.Connection:=Fmain.FDConnection1;
qStatus.Connection:=Fmain.FDConnection1;
qService_user.Connection:=Fmain.FDConnection1;
qShortvada.Connection:=Fmain.FDConnection1;
qService_user.Connection:=Fmain.FDConnection1;
qDocType.Connection:=Fmain.FDConnection1;
qVatPayable.Connection:=Fmain.FDConnection1;
qImp.Connection:=Fmain.FDConnection1;
qUnits.Connection:=Fmain.FDConnection1;
qFacts.Connection:=Fmain.FDConnection1;
qPartn.Connection:=Fmain.FDConnection1;
```

Как можно тоже самое компактно написать в цикле, получить список датасетов (TFDQuery, TFDTable) и в цикле делать присваивание.

Comment: Нет в Делфе классов FDQuery и FDTable. Вероятно имелось ввиду TFDQuery и TFDTable (docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/…)

Comment: компоненты из палитры компонентов на странице Firedac

Comment: Все верно, на палитре элементы называются `Button`, а при добавлении на форму прописывается как объекты и класс - `Button1: TButton`.

Comment: Да, конечно. Классы имел ввиду.  Исправил.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for i := 0 to ComponentCount - 1 do
begin
  if Components[i] is <базовый класс со свойством `.Connection`> then
  begin
    (Components[i] as <базовый класс со свойством `.Connection`>).Connection := Fmain.FDConnection1;
  end;
end;
```

или

```
for i := 0 to ComponentCount - 1 do
begin
  if Components[i] is TFDCustomQuery then
  begin
    (Components[i] as TFDCustomQuery).Connection := Fmain.FDConnection1;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: TFDQuery и TFDTable являются наследниками TFDCustomQuery. Следовательно можно упростить второй пример до **for i := 0 to ComponentCount -1 do if Components[i].InheristFrom(TFDCustomQuery) then (Components[i] as TFDCustomQuery).Connection := Fmain.FDConnection1;**